# How to call RestSharp in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, restsharp

How to call RestSharp in Visual Studio 2013?

I get an error while calling RestSharp with my code:

```
using System;    
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RestSharp; // I have an error here !
```

Comment: Use NuGet to install RestSharp.  To do that Right click on the Project or Solution file in Solution Exporter and select Manage NuGet packages.  Search for it in there and install it.

Comment: work perfect thanks !

Answer (score 9):

The issue might be that you have not installed RestSharp in your solution/references. To add the package go to:

Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console

Then paste this in the console:

```
Install-Package RestSharp
```

[relevant documentation](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console)

Comment: Thank you for the input. I added some explanation/documentation in case someone is interested @chwarr

Comment: Much better answer now. It helps the asker and future readers understand the why behind the steps to take. Thank you.